# Setting {reactive: false} when searching a collection in Meteor still updates the template

Tags: meteor, reactive-programming

I've got a news feed idea I'm trying out in Meteor, but I'm having issues with making the damn thing behave :) I want it to load up the news feed on page load / refresh, but not when the data changes. I found in the documentation that adding `{reactive: false}` to the find method of a collection should make it stick to the results generated on render, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Meteor keeps updating the template right away.

Here's the code I've got:

**On the server side:**

```
Meteor.publish("newsfeed", function () {
    return Newsfeed.find({});
});
```

**On the client side:**

```
Meteor.subscribe('newsfeed');

Template.feed.feed_data = function() {
    var feed = Newsfeed.find({}, {
        sort: {updated_time: -1},
        limit: 10,
        reactive: false
    });

    return feed;
};
```

**In the template:**

```
<template name="feed">
    <div id="feed-wrapper">
        <ul>
            {{#each feed_data}}
                <li>
                    <div class="message">{{message}}</div>
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

If I then run `Newsfeed.update({_id: 'some_random_id'}, {$set: {date_created: 'some_random_date'}})` in Dev Tools, the template updates the sorting of my news feed and changes it.

How do I make it not do that? :D

Comment: On a side note; I tried removing all the autorun functions I had in the project, thinking it might have something to do with another collection being updated at the same time and that somehow triggering the template render, but that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is arguably a bug in Meteor. Passing `reactive: false` means that minimongo itself doesn't set up some code to say "observe and if it changes, invalidate". But `#each` has its own separate observeChanges call which uses the observe callbacks directly (not a reactive "invalidate and recalculate") to update the list.  Probably we should not do this if the cursor has `reactive: false` on it. Track this in https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/771 !

Answer (score 0):

Thats a bit odd, it ought to work. You could also use [preserve](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_preserve):

Try adding this line in your client js

```
Template.feed.preserve(['#feed-wrapper']);
```

Btw is the `template name="feed"` in another template? Does this template have any reactive variables in it?

Comment: Tried adding preserve, that didn't work.

The template is being included from within another template. I tried removing it from the parent template and just adding it right after <body>, but still, if I changed the Collection it got re-rendered on the client side.

Comment: I was able to duplicate this, it might be a bug & I opened an issue on  meteor's github repo describing it.

Comment: Thanks Akshat - if anyone finds this, here's the issue url: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/771

Comment: Collection.find({},{reactive:false}) returns empty in my case. Any ide guys?